# How to check in app purchases list of users purchased on Apple Dashboard

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, react-native-iap

I am using in app purchases
react-native-iap
n this user is making a payment and it is not verified at the backend. So I want to get a list of users who purchased a plan. So i want to know how can I get a list in the App Store dashboard.